# woocommerce message calculate shipping

Tags: woocommerce

Image:

[image]

This message showing up before selecting the country in the "Cart page."

Is it possible that we will change the message after selecting the country where the shipment unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You just can set allowed countries for shipping in woocommerce options(no sense to allow countries where the shipment is unavailable), so only allowed countries will show in select box. Woocommerce -> Settings -> General -> Selling Location(s) -> Sell to specific countries only